# Как реализовать операции одномерного и двумерного массива?

Tags: c++, stl, вектор

Есть некая функция, которая должна реализовать следующую формулу:
есть двумерный вектор:
[1 2][3 4][5 6]
и одномерный вектор равный количеству строк (3) и 2 коэффициента (7 и 8).
Каждую строчку двумерного массива нужно умножить на определенные коэффициенты и сложить числа строки
Например, первый элемент одномерного нужно найти следующим образом:
S[1]=1x7+2x8
S[2]=3x7+4x8 и тд
Как это реализовать? Мой способ не работает

```
std::vector<double> Sums(std::vector<std::vector<double>> pattern, int m, double a1, double a2) {
    std::vector<double> S;
    for (int i = 0; i < m; i++) {
        S[i] = a1 * pattern[i][0] + a2 * pattern[i][1];
    }
    return S;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Строчкой:

```
std::vector<double> S;
```

Вы не выделяете память под элементы, но пытаетесь присвоить `i`-му элементу значение.

```
S[i] = a1 * pattern[i][0] + a2 * pattern[i][1];
```

Вам нужно или изначально выделить память под `m` элементов.

Например вот так:

```
std::vector<double> S(m);
```

Или не изменять значения `i`-го элемента, а добавлять в вектор элемент.

Например вот так:

```
S.push_back(a1 * pattern[i][0] + a2 * pattern[i][1]);
```

Comment: Я реализовал код двумя способами, но ошибка не ушла( Debug Assertion Failed! Expression: vector subscript out of range

Comment: @РоманСвирид хмм странно, выложите полностью код какой нибудь сайт типа `ideone` и скиньте ссылку в комментарий под ответом.

Comment: https://ideone.com/2w07mI

Comment: @РоманСвирид проблема уже в размере `pattern` когда `m = 3` размер `pattern` равен `2` отсюда выход за пределы.